# ubuntu 16.04 xorg crash with AMD R7 370

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, 16.04, amd-graphics

Upgraded 15.10 to 16.04 today. Resulting in Xorg crash and really slow graphics (llvmpipe). With AMD R7 370 graphics card. From error log read: Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in DoConfigure().

What could be the possible solutions to it? At least how to configure llvmpipe to run faster?

I tried to open X-s configuration, but that ended with a crash.

Answer (score 0):

[AMD Dropped support for fglrx](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2016-March/016315.html) and Canonical wont take that on so you only have the open source drivers and they dont work well.  You cant even install the older fglrx driver since 16.04 comes with Xorg 1.18 and they dont support that version.  You are basically SOL until the open drivers get better.  You could try other desktop options. Find my reference [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04).

Comment: Thank You! I solved the problem without really becoming to understand what the root cause was. I upgraded from terminal initially. Then, after running into problems I downloaded iso-image and reinstalled the system from there - and after that it works.